# Playing multiplayer Age of Empires stopped working after switching to new router ASUS RT-N66U

Tags: router, lan, gaming

Playing this old game has never been a problem while my LAN was setup with an old DLINK WBR-2310. I recently switched to a powerful router, the ASUS RT-N66U. Everything goes well on the LAN. Windows PCs can see each other, I share a printer. I was able to play Minecraft on the LAN between several PCs. But when I came back to Age of Empires (which uses TCPIP DirectPlay for multiplayer) no PCs can see the game host. Sometimes, they see it in the list, try to join and then it hangs and fails. Some PCs are wired, others are non wired, so the problem is not specific to one category.I tried to switch the game host, not better.

I thought a router could be difficult to setup in its way to handle the communications with the outside, port forwarding, and so on. But on the LAN with all machines on the same address range...?

Any idea on what could be blocking? Thanks.

Comment: Try adding the game to the Firewall allowed list (Also advanced firewall Outbound/InBound List) and then try the game again. if you problem doesn't solve then note me.

Comment: Well, the firewall of the router is OFF (the firewall is ON at the DSL modem level for the outbound traffic).

Comment: You didn't need to change Router firewall state! You just have to set Windows Firewall and Advanced Firewall settings to allow the game for both "OutBound" and "InBoud". Test it and comment the results.

Comment: I didn't change anything. I'm telling you it's OFF. So, if it's off, this is not the firewall that is blocking anything.

Comment: as far as the Windows firewalls are concerned, they are off in my tests.

Answer (score -1):

I have disabled firewall on the router and it works now.
Go to router admin page
Go to firewall
Disable it

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Although disabling a firewall might solve your problem, it is still a very bad idea. Instead you should look which ports you really need to open, and then do a port forwarding for only those.